# Fixing my responsive navigation on touch devices

Tags: javascript, wordpress, responsive-design

I'm creating a website using _s theme for WordPress and I'm trying to use their native navigation file + some modifications I made in order to use sub menus.

Here the link to the site:
http://www.listsofscholarships.com/

At my computer I can see it working in Chrome or Firefox just like I want it to work but on touch devices the problem is I can't double-tap to close each sub menu.

I tried a few things but I can't seem to get around that, any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Here's the JavaScript for it:

```
/**
 * File navigation.js.
 *
 * Handles toggling the navigation menu for small screens and enables TAB key
 * navigation support for dropdown menus.
 */
( function() {
    var container, button, menu, links, subMenus, i, len;

    container = document.getElementById( 'site-navigation' );
    if ( ! container ) {
        return;
    }

    button = container.getElementsByTagName( 'button' )[0];
    if ( 'undefined' === typeof button ) {
        return;
    }

    menu = container.getElementsByTagName( 'ul' )[0];

    // Hide menu toggle button if menu is empty and return early.
    if ( 'undefined' === typeof menu ) {
        button.style.display = 'none';
        return;
    }

    menu.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
    if ( -1 === menu.className.indexOf( 'nav-menu' ) ) {
        menu.className += ' nav-menu';
    }

    button.onclick = function() {
        if ( -1 !== container.className.indexOf( 'toggled' ) ) {
            container.className = container.className.replace( ' toggled', '' );
            button.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
            menu.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
        } else {
            container.className += ' toggled';
            button.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'true' );
            menu.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'true' );
        }
    };

    // Get all the link elements within the menu.
    links    = menu.getElementsByTagName( 'a' );
    subMenus = menu.getElementsByTagName( 'ul' );

    // Set menu items with submenus to aria-haspopup="true".
    for ( i = 0, len = subMenus.length; i < len; i++ ) {
        subMenus[i].parentNode.setAttribute( 'aria-haspopup', 'true' );
    }

    // Each time a menu link is focused or blurred, toggle focus.
    for ( i = 0, len = links.length; i < len; i++ ) {
        links[i].addEventListener( 'mouseup', toggleFocused, true );
    }

    /**
     * Sets or removes .focus class on an element.
     */
    function toggleFocused(event) {
        var self = this;

        if(document.getElementById('site-navigation').classList.contains('toggled')){

            // Move up through the ancestors of the current link until we hit .nav-menu.
            while ( -1 === self.className.indexOf( 'nav-menu' ) ) {

                // On li elements toggle the class .focus.
                if ( 'li' === self.tagName.toLowerCase() ) {
                    if ( -1 !== self.className.indexOf( 'focus' ) ) {
                        self.className = self.className.replace( ' focus', '' );
                    } else {
                        self.className += ' focus';
                    }
                }

                self = self.parentElement;
            }

        }
    }

    // Each time a menu link is focused or blurred, toggle focus.
    for ( i = 0, len = links.length; i < len; i++ ) {
        links[i].addEventListener( 'touchstart', toggleFocus, true );
    }

    /**
     * Sets or removes .focus class on an element.
     */
    function toggleFocus(event) {
        var self = this;
        return false;
        /*event.preventDefault();*/
        event.stopPropagation();

        if(document.getElementById('site-navigation').classList.contains('toggled')){

            // Move up through the ancestors of the current link until we hit .nav-menu.
            while ( -1 === self.className.indexOf( 'nav-menu' ) ) {

                // On li elements toggle the class .focus.
                if ( 'li' === self.tagName.toLowerCase() ) {
                    if ( -1 !== self.className.indexOf( 'focus' ) ) {
                        self.className = self.className.replace( ' focus', '' );
                    } else {
                        self.className += ' focus';
                    }
                }

                self = self.parentElement;
            }

        }
    }

    /**
     * Toggles `focus` class to allow submenu access on tablets.
     */
    ( function( container ) {
        var touchStartFn, i,
            parentLink = container.querySelectorAll( '.menu-item-has-children > a, .page_item_has_children > a' );

        if ( 'ontouchstart' in window ) {
            touchStartFn = function( e ) {
                var menuItem = this.parentNode, i;

                if ( ! menuItem.classList.contains( 'focus' ) ) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    for ( i = 0; i < menuItem.parentNode.children.length; ++i ) {
                        if ( menuItem === menuItem.parentNode.children[i] ) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        menuItem.parentNode.children[i].classList.remove( 'focus' );
                    }
                    menuItem.classList.add( 'focus' );
                } else {
                    menuItem.classList.remove( 'focus' );
                }
            };

            for ( i = 0; i < parentLink.length; ++i ) {
                parentLink[i].addEventListener( 'touchstart', touchStartFn, false );
            }
        }
    }( container ) );
} )();
```

Comment: That's not ok (to just post a link).  See this http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - the problem is once your link is fixed, this has no value to future visitors.  SO is all about creating value for future visitors, so you need to post your code here, otherwise this will get closed.

Comment: I guess you're right :)  I've added the JS code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the toggleFocus function

```
( function() {
    var container, button, menu, links, subMenus, i, len;

    container = document.getElementById( 'site-navigation' );
    if ( ! container ) {
        return;
    }

    button = container.getElementsByTagName( 'button' )[0];
    if ( 'undefined' === typeof button ) {
        return;
    }

    menu = container.getElementsByTagName( 'ul' )[0];

    // Hide menu toggle button if menu is empty and return early.
    if ( 'undefined' === typeof menu ) {
        button.style.display = 'none';
        return;
    }

    menu.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
    if ( -1 === menu.className.indexOf( 'nav-menu' ) ) {
        menu.className += ' nav-menu';
    }

    button.onclick = function() {
        if ( -1 !== container.className.indexOf( 'toggled' ) ) {
            container.className = container.className.replace( ' toggled', '' );
            button.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
            menu.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
        } else {
            container.className += ' toggled';
            button.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'true' );
            menu.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'true' );
        }
    };

    // Get all the link elements within the menu.
    links    = menu.getElementsByTagName( 'a' );
    subMenus = menu.getElementsByTagName( 'ul' );

    // Set menu items with submenus to aria-haspopup="true".
    for ( i = 0, len = subMenus.length; i < len; i++ ) {
        subMenus[i].parentNode.setAttribute( 'aria-haspopup', 'true' );
    }

    // Each time a menu link is focused or blurred, toggle focus.
    for ( i = 0, len = links.length; i < len; i++ ) {
        links[i].addEventListener( 'mouseup', toggleFocused, true );
    }

    /**
     * Sets or removes .focus class on an element.
     */
    function toggleFocused(event) {
        var self = this;

        if(document.getElementById('site-navigation').classList.contains('toggled')){

            // Move up through the ancestors of the current link until we hit .nav-menu.
            while ( -1 === self.className.indexOf( 'nav-menu' ) ) {

                // On li elements toggle the class .focus.
                if ( 'li' === self.tagName.toLowerCase() ) {
                    if ( -1 !== self.className.indexOf( 'focus' ) ) {
                        self.className = self.className.replace( ' focus', '' );
                    } else {
                        self.className += ' focus';
                    }
                }

                self = self.parentElement;
            }

        }
    }

    // Each time a menu link is focused or blurred, toggle focus.
    for ( i = 0, len = links.length; i < len; i++ ) {
        links[i].addEventListener( 'touchstart', toggleFocus, true );
    }



    /**
     * Toggles `focus` class to allow submenu access on tablets.
     */
    ( function( container ) {
        var touchStartFn, i,
            parentLink = container.querySelectorAll( '.menu-item-has-children > a, .page_item_has_children > a' );

        if ( 'ontouchstart' in window ) {
            touchStartFn = function( e ) {
                var menuItem = this.parentNode, i;

                if ( ! menuItem.classList.contains( 'focus' ) ) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    for ( i = 0; i < menuItem.parentNode.children.length; ++i ) {
                        if ( menuItem === menuItem.parentNode.children[i] ) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        menuItem.parentNode.children[i].classList.remove( 'focus' );
                    }
                    menuItem.classList.add( 'focus' );
                } else {
                    menuItem.classList.remove( 'focus' );
                }
            };

            for ( i = 0; i < parentLink.length; ++i ) {
                parentLink[i].addEventListener( 'touchstart', touchStartFn, false );
            }
        }
    }( container ) );
} )();
```

Comment: I can't believe the answer was so easy and I didn't see it ~_~   Thanks a lot!